# Disparar algum tipo de evento quando um aplicativo for aberto em c#

Tags: windows, processo

Estou precisando impedir que usuários da empresa que trabalho abram muitos aplicativos ao mesmo tempo.
Por exemplo, aplicativo ABC.exe só pode ser aberto uma vez no computador(ou 2x).
Então se já tiver duas instancias do processo ABC.exe aberto no windows, impedir que uma terceira instancia seja aberta.

Pesquisei algo nativo do windows e não encontrei.
Então pensei em criar algum serviço no c# para poder monitorar isso.

Então eis a pergunta. É possivel no C#, verificar algum tipo de evento quando um aplicativo X for iniciar no windows ? Para nesse momento eu verificar quantos processos dele existe ?

Qualquer outra alternativa para me ajudar no problema é bem vinda.